# using signal and alarm as timeouts in C

Tags: c

First thing, I'm new at C. I've inherited some legacy C code. In in this application the time outs aren't working correctly. It uses signal and alarm to create a timeout. I've read up on both and I'm still having a problem.

```
signal(SIGALRM, timeouthandler);
alarm(3);
...(connection to a server that may hang)...

alarm(0);

timeouthandler(){
...(connection to a server that may hang)...
}
```

Now this works fine until I have to add a time out to a different section of the code.

```
signal(SIGALRM, timeouthandler2);
alarm(3);
...(log the time out)...

alarm(0);

timeouthandler2(){
...(log the time out)...
}
```

Why is my second timeout not working? What is the connect between signal and alarm? and is there a cleaner (not to complicated) way of doing this. Also I'm going to need another timeout handler that contains both of these timeouts. Thanks!!

**EDIT**: ok, so it looks like I can't have a two timeouts going at once. Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I have a list of servers that I want to connect to. I want each connect to have 3 seconds to connect and if not to time out. Then I also want a `global` time out for the list of servers so that if the total time for all the connection's time go over 12 second it times out and moves on. Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between a signal and an alarm is that an alarm is a pending signal; that alarm's signal (SIGALRM) will be delivered in the future. `man alarm` for details but the summary is that `alarm(5);` causes SIGALRM to be sent in 5 seconds, and `alarm(0);` cancels the (not-yet-delivered) alarm. Your signal handling function (the second parameter to the `signal()` call) will be called when your signal is sent (and this will suspend main execution of your program until the signal handler returns).

As to why it's not working... what isn't happening? You haven't provided any details.

As to a cleaner way to do things... it's not clear exactly what you're trying to do so it's not possible to answer. Why will `...code...` take more than 3 seconds? If that's understood then your question may be able to be answered.

Comment: ok, so it looks like I can't have a two timeouts going at once. Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I have a list of servers that I want to connect to. I want each connect to have 3 seconds to connect and if not to time out. Then I also want a "global" time out for the list of servers so that if the total time for all the connection's time go over 12 second it times out and moves on. Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Other ways to do this will depend on your OS. If your OS has proper support for posix semaphores, you can split the task into a second thread. Your main thread will start the second thread, then wait for a semaphore from that thread to indicate the task is complete; this semaphore wait will be done with `sem_timedwait()` so that you can time out. The worker thread will try to connect to a single server and if successful, sets a flag (so the main thread knows the status) and posts the semaphore (to wake the main thread immediately). The 12 second global timeout might be done with an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of seconds is zero, then it won't schedule a new alarm. From the [`alarm` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm):

> If seconds is zero, no new alarm() is scheduled.

But also:

> In any event any previously set alarm() is canceled.

So by calling `alarm` a second time in you cancel any previously set alarm.

Answer (score 0):

[`alarm(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/alarm.2.html) schedules `SIGALRM` signal delivered to the process in given number of seconds, *canceling* previous requests. You can't have multiple timeouts set like this. It's one or nothing.

If you are on Linux, you might want to explore pollable [`timerfd`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) facility.